# Obter nome da constraint e drop em seguida

Tags: sql, oracle

Eu tenho uma `constraint` `UNIQUE` na tabela PESSOA e é do campo `CPF`.
Para obter o nome desta contraint eu uso a query:

```
SELECT UC.CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS UC
INNER JOIN USER_TAB_COLUMNS UT ON UT.TABLE_NAME = UC.TABLE_NAME
WHERE UC.TABLE_NAME = 'PESSOA' AND UC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'U' AND UT.COLUMN_NAME = 'CPF';
```

Como faço um procedimento onde primeiro eu pego este nome e dou o drop na mesma?

Answer (score 2):

Basta realizar sua consulta e fazer um "alter table drop constraint", ex:

```
create or replace procedure DropConstraint(aTabela          varchar2,
                                           aCONSTRAINT_TYPE varchar2,
                                           aCOLUMN_NAME     varchar2) is
  cursor cConstraints is
    SELECT UC.CONSTRAINT_NAME
      FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS UC
     INNER JOIN USER_TAB_COLUMNS UT
        ON UT.TABLE_NAME = UC.TABLE_NAME
     WHERE UC.TABLE_NAME = aTabela
       AND UC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = aCONSTRAINT_TYPE
       AND UT.COLUMN_NAME = aCOLUMN_NAME;
begin
  for c in cConstraints loop
    execute immediate ('ALTER TABLE ' || aTabela || '  DROP CONSTRAINT ' ||
                      c.CONSTRAINT_NAME);
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Onde eu coloco o nome da tabela, coluna, etc ?

Comment: ué, conforme você perguntou, eu montei um procedimento que faz o drop de constraints, basta chamar este em um bloco anônimo passando por parâmetro conforme sua necessidade.

Comment: Explicar melhor sua dúvida @Douglas